# A program aborts when strcpying over a char in a union

Tags: c, string, pointers, clang, unions

I am trying to `strcpy` to a union of size 8, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef union {
  double num;
  char chr;
} doublechar;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  doublechar test;
  strcpy(&test, "test");
  printf("%s\n", &test);

  return 0;
}
```

This works fine. However, when I try to copy to the address of the union as a character with `strcpy` or `strncpy`, the program crashes with an `abort` message:

```
strcpy(&test.chr, "test"); // this does not work
strncpy(&test.chr, "test", 3); // this does not work
strcpy(&test.num, "test"); // this works
memcpy(&test.chr, "test", 3); // this works
```

In all four of these cases, the memory address is the same, so why do some of them fail? `strcpy` and `strncpy` don't seem to work with a heap-allocated union either. Additionally, this seems to work fine even though it shouldn't:

```
char *p = &test.chr;
strcpy(p, "test"); // this works
```

Can anyone explain this?

EDIT:
Obviously, the compiler produces a bunch of warnings when this program is compiled, but all of those have to do with printf format specifiers. Here's a version of the program that compiles cleanly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef union {
  double num;
  char chr;
} doublechar;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  doublechar test;
  strcpy(&test.chr, "test");
  printf("%s\n", &test.chr);

  return 0;
}
```

I am using the following compiler:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

This is what I see when I run the program:

```
[1]    74379 abort      a.out
```

Comment: You tried walking on very thin ice and fell through.

Comment: Your compiler should have emitted diagnostic for all versions of your program. If it didn't, throw away your compiler and get a modern free one. If it did, fix your program so that the compiler no longer complains. It makes no sense to discuss behaviour of a program that doesn't compile cleanly. Always use `-Wall -Werror` or equivalent.

Comment: I have edited my post. My program compiles without warnings and behaves the same.

Comment: Now your program just contains undefined behaviour. Some compilers will still warn you about it.  `strcpy(&test.chr,...)` is only allowed to copy one character. The fact that `test` itself has larger size is irrelevant.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", &test);` causes undefined behaviour (the argument for `%s` must have type `char *` or `char const *`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple. You've defined `test` as a `doublechar`, and `test.chr` is therefore a **single character**.  When you take a  pointer to it, it behaves for the purposes of indexing [as if it were a pointer to the first element of an array **of length 1**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p7).

And here,

```
strcpy(&test.chr, "test");
```

you're trying to copy an array of length **5** over array of length **1**, and the behaviour is undefined. It does not matter whether it is the same address as `&test.num` - because that is not the only thing that matters; what matters too is the type of the addressed element, the element's location within the (possible) array it belongs to and the pointer's provenance.

In the past this could have been a "non-issue", because the undefined behaviour means that an implementation that overruns the array of length 1 with 4 more characters would have been correct. Now compilers and C implementations are implementing range checking in builtin functions, and `strcpy` can guard that you do not write out of bounds of a *known* array of length 1, and aborts the program before worse behaviour occurs. That *too* is allowed by the standard.

The definition of undefined behaviour is [3.4.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p1)

> 1. undefined behavior behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International
>      Standard imposes no requirements
> 2. NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>      or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>      environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), **to
>      terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>      diagnostic message).**

---

The fix for your program would be to state your intentions clearly. Perhaps this would be better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef union {
    double num;
    char chrs[sizeof (double)];
} doublechar;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  doublechar test;
  strcpy(test.chrs, "test");
  printf("%s\n", test.chrs);

  return 0;
}
```

---

For the record, GCC Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 behaves somewhat better with your last excerpt - it issues **proper diagnostics**:

```
% gcc union.c -O3
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:494:0,
                 from union.c:2:
In function ‘strcpy’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at union.c:13:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:90:10: warning: 
   ‘__builtin___memcpy_chk’ writing 5 bytes into a region of size 1 overflows the 
   destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   return __builtin___strcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __bos (__dest));
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

% ./a.out        
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./a.out terminated
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Here, just using the default switches is not sufficient; the one compiled without optimization would print `test`.

Answer (score -1):

This

```
strcpy(&test, "test");
```

is not correct, compiler could have warn you like below if you had compile your code with flag like `-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpedantic -Werror`. Never ignore compiler warning.

> error: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
>   [-Werror]    strcpy(&test, "test");    ^

as `&test` is of `doublechar*` type and `"test"` is of `char*` type & copying `char*` to `doublechar*` results in above error message.

Also here

```
typedef union {
  double num; /* 8 byte gets allocated for whole union as this member needs the highest memory */
  char chr;
} doublechar;
```

`doublechar` is union i.e here all members shares the common mmory which is `8` byte in `32-bit` system

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 |                         |                        |
  --------------------------------------------------
 MSB                                           <-- LSB
                                                   num
                                                   chr <-- both num and chr access memory from beginning
```

Also this

```
strcpy(&test.chr, "test"); // this does not work
printf("%s\n", &test); /* format specifier is wrong */
```

causes **undefined behavior** as `test.chr` is of `char` type, copying more than `1` `char` is not recommended as it may overwrite next member content, point is be careful while doing so.

Also `printf` format specifier are not correct, `%s` expects argument of `char*` and `&test` type is not of `char*`. You want like below

```
strcpy(&test.chr, "t"); /* test.chr is of char type, */
printf("%c\n", test.chr); /* use %c as chr is of char type*/
printf("%p\n",(void*)&test); /* use %p if you want to print address */
```

Also here

> strcpy(&test.num, "test"); // this works

**No, it doesn't work** as `test.num` is of `double` type not `char*` type, your compiler could have warned you like

> note: expected ‘char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘double
>   *’

you may want to use `memcpy()` in above case.

Comment: Compiler warnings aside, why does `strcpy(&test.chr, ...)` crash when `strcpy(&test.num, ...)` doesn't, despite the fact that the two have the same address?

Comment: yes `&test.num` and `&test.chr` results in same address but what you are copying onto those address is wrong.

Comment: This `printf("%s\n", &test);` is completely wrong. why `&` ? If you want to print address of union, use `%p` not `%s`. Since `test.chr` is of `char` type not `char*` type you should use `%c`. for e.g  `strcpy(&test.chr, "t");  printf("%p\n",(void*)&test.chr); printf("%c\n",test.chr);`

Comment: I understand how format specifiers work. I am not trying to print the address of the union, I am trying to print the bytes I have written to it as a string, so `printf("%s\n", &test)` is exactly what I intended. Here's my question: when I declare `doublechar test`, 8 bytes are allocated on the stack. I can write to these bytes and print out the result ([like so](https://gist.github.com/AjayMT/fbe3c6d662461bbe5e903940d2ce8d8a)), except with strcpy when I give it the address of a character. Why?